# Date Modified Column not showing full date this year

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2016, administration, date-time

The date modified column on my SharePoint 2016 on-premises is showing only the day and not the full date for just this year (2024).

I have checked other libraries, and this is all over. Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks.

[image: full date missing example]

Comment: Go to "Modified" column settings page and set "Display Format" to "Standard". Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP yes thanks that worked.  I was changing it at the site collection level and it was not changing.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. I have added it as an answer below with detailed steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below steps to show the date column value in Standard date format:

1. Go to your SharePoint list.
2. Click on **LIST** tab from the top and select **List settings**:

   [image]
3. From list settings page, scroll down to **Columns** section and click on **Modified** column name.
4. Set **Display Format** to **Standard** and click **OK** to save the changes:

   [image]
5. Now your list should show the date column values in full date format.